# Ordering selectInput Choices

Tags: r, shiny

I need to order some choices of my `selectInput()`:

```
selectInput(
      "aqadoaco",
      label = "Steel:",
      choices= c("", dfMateriais$AQA_QT),
      multiple = T
    )
```

Nevertheless, when I look at my choices, they show as below:

[image]

The choices are not ordered. What kind of syntax can I use to order this?

Thanks!

Comment: If `dfMateriais$AQA_QT` is a vector I assume that a  `sort()` on the vector should work (in case you wanna order alphabetically)

Comment: It works! Many thanks man! -- sort(c("", dfMateriais$AQA_QT))

Comment: Nice ! :). `sort(dfMateriais$AQA_QT)` should work as well.